# Watchdog run function once

Tags: python, watchdog

Below is my watchdog script. When a file is modified in Vim, the deleted then created events are fired. [This is expected.](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog#about-using-watchdog-with-editors-like-vim)

This leads to the problem. I would like it to ignore the deleted event on file modification with Vim and run the modified function, but run the deleted function when a file is actually deleted.

Is this possible without changing my Vim config?

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

WATCH_PATH = './files'

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        if event == 'modified':
            modified(event.src_path)
        if event == 'created':
            created(event.src_path)
        if event == 'deleted':
            deleted(event.src_path)

def modified(src):
    print(src, 'modified')

def created(src):
    print(src, 'created')

def deleted(src):
    print(src, 'deleted')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    eh = Handler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(eh, path=WATCH_PATH, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

**Log**

```
2020-04-26 03:47:02 - Deleted file: ./files/a.txt
2020-04-26 03:47:02 - Modified directory: ./files
2020-04-26 03:47:10 - Created file: ./files/a.txt
2020-04-26 03:47:10 - Modified directory: ./files
```

**Vim**

Vim is configured so that temporary files are not stored in the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the problem better, I have modified your code a little bit.

```
...
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, LoggingEventHandler
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # eh = Handler()
  eh = LoggingEventHandler()

  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                      format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                      datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

  observer = Observer()
  ...
```

Replacing `FileSystemEventHandler` with `LoggingEventHandler` in the `main` function, it will generates the log of the events. On modifying a text file in the directory './file' , logs generated as follows:

```
2020-04-26 12:41:25 - Created file: ./files/b.txt~
2020-04-26 12:41:25 - Modified directory: ./files
2020-04-26 12:41:25 - Modified file: ./files/b.txt~
2020-04-26 12:41:25 - Modified file: ./files/b.txt
2020-04-26 12:41:25 - Modified file: ./files/b.txt
2020-04-26 12:41:25 - Deleted file: ./files/b.txt~
2020-04-26 12:41:25 - Modified directory: ./files
```

Here the deleted file is the `b.txt~` which is the intermediate file and not your original file. So you just need to filter out the events of intermediate files.

Here is the code with the fix:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, LoggingEventHandler

WATCH_PATH = './files'

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_any_event(self, event):

        if str(event.src_path).endswith("~"):
            return None

        if event.event_type == 'modified':
            modified(event.src_path)
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            created(event.src_path)
        elif event.event_type == 'deleted':
            deleted(event.src_path)

def modified(src):
    print(src, 'modified')

def created(src):
    print(src, 'created')

def deleted(src):
    print(src, 'deleted')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    eh = Handler()

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(eh, path=WATCH_PATH, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping the observer...")
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Output:

```
./files modified
./files/b.txt modified
./files modified
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time on this, but it doesn't have the desired effect. I don't see any files ending with ~ in the output when using `LoggingEventHandler`.

Comment: Can you post the logs? Also to note that using "Vim" and "nano" editor, you may find the intermediate files in this format "abc.txt.swp" rather than "abc.txt~"

Comment: Added log to question content.

Comment: Try editing the file by opening it and write something in that file and save it. Then check the logs. If you have already done that then please try using other text editor.

Comment: The log is almost identical after writing something in the file and saving it. Nano shows only modified.

Comment: There must be something wrong on your side because when I used Nano editor to edit the file, it reflected on the logs and intermediate file with ".swp" extension generated and deleted.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with Nano, but Vim is configured so that temporary files aren't stored in the working directory.